# Issues Using CustomData in sap.ui.table.TreeTable Template

Tags: sapui5

I've been trying to use [CustomData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.CustomData/) in sap.ui.TreeTable. I pass the value for CustomData from my ODataModel but I've been getting errors like

> CustomData with key cssColor should be written to HTML of Element sap.m.Text#__text25-__clone22 but the value is not a string.

So I used formatter to pass a string to the value:

```
<t:Column
  resizable="false"
  width="5.5rem"
  sortProperty="CMPlan"
>
  <t:multiLabels>
    <Text
      text="{i18n>currMonth}"
      textAlign="Center"
      width="100%"
      class="boldHeader"
    />
    <Text
      text="{i18n>plan}"
      textAlign="Center"
      width="100%"
      class="boldHeader"
    />
  </t:multiLabels>
  <t:template>
    <Text
      width="100%"
      text="{treeJSONModel>Plan}"
    >
      <customData>
        <core:CustomData
          key="cssColor"
          value="{
            path: 'treeJSONModel>colorCode',
            formatter: '.formatter.colorString'
          }"
          writeToDom="true"
        />
      </customData>
    </Text>
  </t:template>
</t:Column>
```

And in my formatter, I have a function like below:

```
colorString: function(value) {
  if (value === "YELLOW") {
    return "YELLOW";
  } else {
    return "noColor";
  }
},
```

The number of error I get has been reduced but still I see this error in my console

> CustomData with key cssColor should be written to HTML of Element sap.m.Text#__text37-__clone40 but the value is not a string.

Any solutions to help me rectify this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a (quick & dirty) way to handle the errors.

I followed your approach and made a formatter:

```
formatCell: function (iValue) {
        try {
            iValue.toString();
        } catch (err){
            iValue = "foo";
        }
        return iValue.toString();
    }
```

basically I force the Value (in every possible way) to be a String...
It throws an error if you try `toString()` on `null` so I just assign a dummy String...

I assume the error only gets thrown if you assign `null` to your customData